what's the purpose of dependent claims?
In order for someone to infringe on a dependent claim, the infringer must also have infringed upon the independent claim.
If that's the case, then having only the independent claim would be enough to prevent potential infringers?

In an ideal world the purpose of dependent claims is almost solely to provide a fallback position if prior art is discovered that renders the independent claim obvious. It is hoped that the details added in dependent claims help to inch farther from the "obviousness radius" of the potentially newly discovered prior art.
Due to this not being an ideal world there is also the effect that a judge or jury will be more likely to side with the patentee if an alleged infringer has been practicing exactly what is recited in a narrow dependent claim, rather than merely what is recited in a broader independent claim.
I would be skeptical that a patent application is in the very best shape it can be if it has no dependent claims, especially in the field of computers/software.

In addition to the good answer by buff36 there is the subtle effect of the doctrine of claim differentiation. This holds that claims are presumed to have different scopes and particularly that a dependent claim is narrower than the claim it depends from.
If claim 1 says “A machine . . .” and claim 2 says “The machine of claim 1 comprising transistors . . .” Then the doctrine holds that claim 1 covers machines that do not include transistors. Otherwise the claims would have identical scope and the verbage in claim 2 was superfluous.
